# How do I copy a file on a Google Drive using v3 of the Google Drive Java API?

Tags: java, scala, google-drive-api

I'm having trouble copying a file on a Google Drive using v3 of the Google Drive API for Java.

The file in question is on a shared team drive, and I'm reading in credentials that are associated with a service account. The service account has "manager" access to the drive in question.

Here is my code that is trying to copy the file. It's in Scala, rather than Java, but hopefully it will be clear enough anyway, even if you don't know Scala. (In case you don't already know, Scala is a programming language that targets the JVM and interoperates with Java in a relatively painless manner.)

```
    val fileCopy = new GFile()
    fileCopy.setName("Test Copy")
    try {
      ArchiveDriveService
        .files()
        .copy(TemplateFileId, fileCopy)
        .execute()
    } catch {
      case e: IOException =>
        fprint("An error occured: " + e)
    }
```

*[Erratum: As pointed out in the accepted solution provided by ziganotschka below, the only thing I needed to do to get things working right was to add `.setSupportsAllDrives(true)` before the `.execute()` above.]*

Note that `GFile` is just an alias for `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File`. And `ArchiveDriveService` is a variable I defined to hold my `Drive` service object. `TemplateFileId` contains the ID of the Google Drive file that I want to copy.

This is the error that I get when I run this:

```
     {
       "code" : 404,
       "errors" : [ {
         "domain" : "global",
         "location" : "fileId",
         "locationType" : "parameter",
         "message" : "File not found: 1BjvZG6Ub7smBWrhC82aRD2LRUehB_U6AhmnXwrsuLks.",
         "Reason" : "notFound"
       } ],
       "message" : "File not found: 1BjvZG6Ub7smBWrhC82aRD2LRUehB_U6AhmnXwrsuLks."
     }
```

Desipte the above error, `ArchiveDriveService` works fine for getting a ***list*** of files from the drive. E.g., this code works fine:

```
    val result = ArchiveDriveService
      .files()
      .list()
      .setCorpora("drive")
      .setDriveId(driveId)
      .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
      .setIncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true)
      .setPageSize(10)
      .setSpaces("drive")
      .setSupportsAllDrives(true)
      .execute()

    val files = result.getFiles()
    if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
        fprint("No files found.")
    } else {
        fprint("Files:")
        for (file <- files.asScala) {
          fprint(s"${file.getName} (${file.getId})")
        }
    }
```

If I run the above, I get the following output:

```
     Files: 
     Copy of Template for Double Stranded (plasmid NGS, gDNA NGS) calculator (12_UODoLGbN04btC3dKh1yWV0yblGzMe0jEM-FWibVSM)
     Copy of Template for Double Stranded (plasmid NGS, gDNA NGS) calculator (1B0RUHZlakDLfH-12czZAzgABv3pGDhZXD-GIyeXgARA)
     Template for Double Stranded (plasmid NGS, gDNA NGS) calculator (1BjvZG6Ub7smBWrhC82aRD2LRUehB_U6AhmnXwrsuLks)
     Double Stranded Sheet (1MZAf4L0tPiqxW3yNG1oFigEkVjZB1G98)
     test (1zIayPNDWHNscbPdVYBICF001l-TbbZTl)
     foo (1tLlflOLg5OJ7w-YGRloWF-ShriRkrvTO4WV6-X9nl5A)
     foo.xlsx (1BF8--UOriadQSxF0kWMr9-Z0bRepcntI)
     Template for Double Stranded (plasmid NGS, gDNA NGS) calculator.xlsx (1qXAW1BCaFJDUxKd20LJB7haBmf4YCGkc)
     build.sbt (1OqG1iTc0fzcwbszc2-H-rhiq-3jNJpEw)
```

You can see from the above listing, that one of the files listed is the file that I'm trying to copy. I.e., it has the `fileId` "1BjvZG6Ub7smBWrhC82aRD2LRUehB_U6AhmnXwrsuLks". And yet the error message I'm getting says that this file cannot be found.

This is how I'm making `ArchiveDriveService`:

```
  val ArchiveDriveService = newDriveService(ArchiveCredentialsFilename)

  def newDriveService(credentialsFilename: String): Drive = {
    new Drive.Builder(HttpTransport,
                      TheJsonFactory,
                      new HttpCredentialsAdapter(getCredentials(credentialsFilename)))
      .setApplicationName(ApplicationName)
      .build()
  }

  def getCredentials(credentialsFilename: String): GoogleCredentials = {
    val parent = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"))
    val secrets = parent.resolve(".secrets")
    val credentialsPath = secrets.resolve(credentialsFilename)
    val in = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath.toFile)

    // This scope gives us full read/write access to the shared drive:
    val scopes = List(DriveScopes.DRIVE).asJava

    val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(in).createScoped(scopes)
    in.close()
    credentials
  }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When you copy a file that is located on a shared Drive, you need to specify the same like for listing it:

### `.setSupportsAllDrives(true)`

See [parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy?#parameters) of `Files: copy`:

> supportsAllDrives
> Whether the requesting application supports
> both My Drives and shared drives. (Default: false)

- Mind that by default the file will be copied into the same (shared) folder / drive where the original file is located
- If you want to copy it elsewhere, you nedd to specify the `parents[]` parameter